# Will audio settings sync between AppleTV, AirPods Max and an iPad Pro

Tags: macos, appletv, airpods

I have an AppleTV and AirPods Max.  If I buy an iPad Pro and change the bass setting on the iPad will these bass settings transfer over (synchronize) to my AppleTV and the desktop Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Yes, you need an iOS / iPadOS device to set up equalizer settings and update the firmware on your AirPods in my experience.

No, I don’t see sound profiles transferring between devices currently.

Apple handles the update process - here is the article that describes it as a “periodically while charging” scenario.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213317

If after a week of pairing, you would be best opening a support case if you feel you missed an update.

Comment: is there a guide to update the firmware on mac os for the air pods max?

Comment: Yes - see my edit @Im-So-Void